# SQL Error [08004]: Socket connection to server failed. Check your server is reachable from this client on the host:port specified

Tags: sql, informix

I want to join two tables via two databases and connect them to each other via two database servers. I use as database "Informix" in version 14.10 and as sql client "[DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) ".

My SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT      column1 
FROM        databaseA@MyServer1:informix.tableA as A
INNER JOIN  databaseB@MyServer2:informix.tableB as B on A.column1 = tableB.column1
WHERE       column1 IN (10, 20)
```

I thought the SQL query is correct, however I get the following error message:

```
SQL Error [08004]: Socket connection to server (MyServer1, conerr=-25555, oserr=0) failed. Check your server is reachable from this client on the host:port specified.
```

I can access these two servers and its databases and tables.

Questions:

- How can I check if my two servers are reachable from this client?
- No port was specified by me. Do I need to specify a port in the SQL query and if so how do I do that?

Comment: Unrelated, but your join would look better as `... as B on A.column1 = B.column1`. Also, your select and where clause will create an ambiguous column error because both tables have column1. You need to specify which column1 to evaluate, such as `a.column1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. The mistake I made was that the database server name was not the correct one.

The server name in my case had to have a postfix `'_tli'` and the name should then be `myserver1_tli`.

How do I find out what the correct database server name is?

1. Open dbaccess in your console with the following command:

   [image]
2. Choose "DATABASE"
   [image]
3. Choose "Select"
   [image]

Now you should see a list of all databases on your database server. The server name is displayed after the @ sign. Example `name_of_table@your_database_server_name` . So the database server name is `your_database_server_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You mention `connerr = -25555`.  You can find out what that means with:

```
$ finderr -25555
-25555  Server server-name is not listed as a dbserver name in sqlhosts.

The database server name that is mentioned in the current command is
not listed in the sqlhosts file. Check the server name for accuracy.
Check that all database servers to be accessed are included in the
sqlhosts file.

If you are using IBM Informix SE, your current working directory might be
an NFS-mounted directory. Change your current working directory to a
local directory, or add appropriate local directories to your DBPATH.

$
```

That implies that the `sqlhosts` file (normally `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts`, but you can set then environment variable `INFORMIXSQLHOSTS` to specify a different file) does not contain an entry for `Myserver1`.

If you have an Informix DBSA (database server administrator, often colloquially confused with DBA, database administrator, though the two roles are formally distinct in Informix), then contact them for advice on how to set up the `sqlhosts` file on your machine.

If you are the Informix DBSA, then you need to know where your two Informix server instances (`Myserver1` and `Myserver2` in your query) are located, and how you can communicate with them.  The `sqlhosts` file should contain at lest two entries similar to these:

```
myserver1    olsoctcp    hostname1    12345
myserver2    olsoctcp    hostname2    23456
```

The first column is the (Informix) server name, conventionally written in lower-case.  (I don't think the use of `Myserver1` instead of `myserver1` is a cause of the trouble, but it might be simpler to check that.)  The second column says you'll connect to the server via TCP sockets (`ol` for 'online', and older name for Informix Dynamic Server; `soc` for 'sockets', `tcp` for TCP — look in the manuals for alternatives).  The third column identifies the machine on which the database server is found (`hostname1` and `hostname2` in the example).  And the fourth column identifies the service name or port number on which the Informix server is listening.  There can be extra values after these four columns, but they have specialized purposes.  The hostnames for the two entries could be the same, but then the port numbers must be different.  The port numbers for the two entries could be the same, but then the hostnames must be different.

You need to ensure that the two database servers are configured with a listener thread listening on the ports you've specified.  That will means you'll have an entry in the `$ONCONFIG` file for each server similar to:

```
NETTYPE             soctcp,1,50,NET
```

The creates a NET VP (virtual processor) that will listen for up to 50 concurrent sessions via the `soctcp` protocol.  The `DBSERVERNAME` entry in the $`$ONCONFIG` file or one of the entries in one of the `DBSERVERALIASES` lines needs to match the server name (`Myserver1` or `Myserver2`).

The online configuration file is identified by the environment variable `$ONCONFIG`.  It contains the base name for a file found in `$INFORMIXDIR/etc` (so `ONCONFIG=myserver1.cfg` means the file `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/myserver1.cfg`).